# In react with hooks, how do I loop through list and only get certain items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I have a list, that I'm showing in a table, then updating the last column based on a checkbox.  Now I want to get just the values that have been flagged as checked.  I've confirmed from my console logs that the last column is getting updated with the correct value.

Here is my code that I'm using to add to:

```
  const addToPool = () => {
    setDiePool([
      ...diePool,
      {
        dp1 : poolCount,
        dp2 : diceType,
        dp3 : diceNumber,
        dp4 : diceAdjuster,
        dp5 : diceAlias,
        dp6 : poolStatus
      }
    ]);
    setPoolCount(poolCount+1);
  };
```

Here is my code that I'm using to update the column with the "checked" status.  The list may contain several items that are checked.  The calculations are not run when the item is checked, but on click of another button.

```
  const handleSelectItem = (die) => {
    setDiePool(diePool.map(diePool => {
         if(diePool.dp1 !== die.dp1) return diePool
         if(diePool.dp6 == "checked"){
          return {...diePool, dp6: ""}
         }
         else {
          return {...diePool, dp6: "checked"}
         }         
    }))
  };
```

dp6 is the field that contains "checked" or "".  Now, when I click a "Final Result" button, I want to get the records that have "checked" and do calculations with those values.  I want to return a final calculation based on the values I get.  How do I do that?

** Clarification:
I want a button:

```
<Button onClick={showResult}>Show Results</Button>
```

and then perform calculations using the list's values, without changing the list.

```
  const showResults = () => {
    //Run through the diePool list and add up the values if dp6 == checked
    //Return value, without altering the list
  };
```

I tried this, but it didn't like the if statement:

```
  const showResult = diePool.map((die) => 
    //if(die.dp6 == "checked"){
      <li>{die.dp1}</li>
    //}
  );
```

** Update
I might be able to convert the map to an array, then loop through it.  Still working on a solution.

```
  const dResult = Object.values(diePool);
  for(let x = 0; x < dResult.length; x++){
    if (dResult[x].dp6 == "checked"){
      //console.log(dResult[x].dp1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
diePool.filter(diePoolItem => diePoolItem.dp6 === "checked")
```

Comment: Won't a filter remove items that don't equal "checked"?  I don't want to alter the list.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: `filter` doesn't modify the original array, it returns a new one. So theres no risk of modifying your original. Filter would work, but you'd have to chain `.map` after to return your jsx.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const handleSelectItem = (die) => {
    setDiePool(diePool.map(diePool => {
         if(diePool.dp1 !== die.dp1) return [...diePool]
         else if(diePool.dp6 == "checked"){
          return [...diePool, {dp6: ""}]
         }
         else {
          return [...diePool, {dp6: "checked"}]
         }         
    }))   };
```

Comment: The handleSelectItem should only mark the item as checked.  Since multiple items can be checked, the calculations will be run after a different button is clicked.

Comment: The handleSelectItem has to do with the checkbox, and is only included to help show how the list is added to, and then updated.  I've edited the original question to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the `if` because you omitted the `{}` which is short-hand for:

```js
const showResult = diePool.map((die) => {
  return (
    if(die.dp6 == "checked"){
      <li>{die.dp1}</li>
    }
  )
});
```

which makes it a little more apparent as to why its invalid.

Here is one way you could re-format the function to be correct:

```js
const showResult = diePool.map((die) => {
  if(die.dp6 == "checked"){
    return <li>{die.dp1}</li>
  }
});
```

Another option in one line would be:

```js
const showResult = diePool.filter(die => die.dp6 == "checked").map(die => <li>{die.dp1}</li>);
```

However, this will not work with the button you gave, since event handlers expect a void return, and this function returns JSX to be rendered.

You could refactor your button to have some kind of functionality like this:

```js
const [show, toggleShow] = useState(false);

...
// The button just toggles if its hidden or visible
<Button onClick={() => toggleShow(prev => !prev}>Show Results</Button>
// If its visible, render the array of JSX, else null
{show ? showResult : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions you may implement.

One is to add an object as a state variable and track the index of a checked element. You can add the logic for this in your 'handleSelectItem'. As to why an object, just because it's faster to delete and check for existence. Then, your final results function will iterate through the Object.keys of this object and do stuff with each diePool element that was checked.

The other one is what you suggested, using diePool.map and using an if, but adding some logic to not modify the objects of the diePool array (keep in mind that modifying objects inside an array will change the original objects of the original array). Also, if you happen to have objects as dp1, dp2, etc, be extra careful.

As to what the final result function does, I can't help you without more information about what you want to calculate. Hope it's easy for you to figure out having solved the tracking part.

---

By the way, this piece of code repeats the 'diePool' name for a variable. It's probably working due to scopes, but for the sake of readable code I would change the mapped variable's name to 'item', 'diePoolItem' or something of the sort.

```js
  const handleSelectItem = (die) => {
    setDiePool(diePool.map(diePool => {
         if(diePool.dp1 !== die.dp1) return diePool
         if(diePool.dp6 == "checked"){
          return {...diePool, dp6: ""}
         }
         else {
          return {...diePool, dp6: "checked"}
         }         
    }))
  };
```